# C# linq query All method

Tags: c#, linq

Have a collection

```
List<<KeyValuePair<string, Person>>
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int MealType { get; set; }
}

patientEffort.Add("1", new Person() { FirstName = "Raja", LastName = "Ram", MealType = 2 });

patientEffort.Add("2", new Person() { FirstName = "Vijay", LastName = "Anthony", MealType = 1 });
patientEffort.Add("2", new Person() { FirstName = "Vijay", LastName = "Anthony", MealType = 2 });
patientEffort.Add("2", new Person() { FirstName = "Vijay", LastName = "Anthony", MealType = 3 });


patientEffort.Add("3", new Person() { FirstName = "Dr", LastName = "APJ", MealType = 1 });
patientEffort.Add("3", new Person() { FirstName = "Dr", LastName = "APJ", MealType = 2 });
patientEffort.Add("3", new Person() { FirstName = "Dr", LastName = "APJ", MealType = 3 });
patientEffort.Add("3", new Person() { FirstName = "Dr", LastName = "APJ", MealType = 4 });
List<int> _listMealType = new List<int>();
```

If _listMealType= [2]  passed  then Result will be

```
{Key: "1", FirstName = "Raja", LastName = "Ram"}
{Key: "2", FirstName = "Vijay", LastName = "Anthony"}
{Key: "3", FirstName = "Dr", LastName = "APJ"}
```

If _listMealType= [1,2,3]  passed  then Result will be

```
 {Key: 2, FirstName = "Vijay", LastName = "Anthony"}
 {Key: 3, FirstName = "Dr", LastName = "APJ"}
```

If _listMealType= [1,2,3,4] passed then Result will be

```
 {Key: "3", FirstName = "Dr", LastName = "APJ"} only
```

Key may be string or int that doesn't matter. May I have linq query for this scenario. I have used All method is linq but not worked.

```
var query = patientEffort.Where(d => _listMealType.All(x => x == d.Value.MealType)).Select(d => d.Key);
```

Could you please help me in solving the query issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Your sample code is just a mix of snippets - it would really help if you'd put it together as a short but *complete* example. Why are you representing the first value as a string when it's presumably meant to be an integer? What are you expecting the result type to be? You say you've used All and it didn't work, but you haven't shown *how* you used All, or what happened.

Comment: We can assume that string as int  too. Return a key which satisfy the condition.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Strings aren't ints. Please update your question to be much clearer. Likewise "return a key" doesn't fit well with the results you've already described. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: var query = patientEffort.Where(d => _listMealType.All(x => x == d.Value.MealType));

Comment: Please *edit your question* to include what you've tried - ideally as part of the short-but-complete example - and explain the expected results vs actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it helps:

```
        var patients = patientEffort.GroupBy(x => x.Value.FirstName);
        var result = (from patient in patients let res = patient.Select(note => note.Value.MealType).ToList() where _listMealType.Intersect(res).Count() == _listMealType.Count select patient.First()).ToList();
```

Here is variant without linq using:

```
        var patients = patientEffort.GroupBy(x => x.Value.FirstName);   // group patients by name
        foreach (var patient in patients)
        {
            var res = new List<int>();
            foreach (var note in patient)  // collect all meal types of current patient
                res.Add(note.Value.MealType);

            if (_listMealType.Intersect(res).Count() == _listMealType.Count)  // if intersection count equal to source meal list - it's our patient.
                result.Add(patient.First());  // add information about patient. because we need only name - we can use first record in list.
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Artem! It Worked.

Comment: It's really hard to read though, I'd break that statement up into IQueryables var's so the next person can read step by step what is going on

Comment: Don't worry about it, updated in answer. But because owner asked about linq - I converted it to linq :)

Comment: Actually the linq is fine, just needs a few new lines and it's clear what's happening